# VSCode devcontainer failing when docker build takes some more time

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some problems with devcontainer.

My setup is simple, `.devcontainer` folder with `devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "Ubuntu",
    "build": {
        "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
    },
    "extensions": [ "nadako.vshaxe" ],
    "forwardPorts": [ 3000 ],
    "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

And `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM haxe:4.2-bullseye

ARG USERNAME=vscode
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME && \
    useradd \
      --uid ${USER_UID} \
      --gid ${USER_GID} \
      --create-home \
      --shell /bin/bash \
      ${USERNAME}

RUN apt-get upgrade && \
    apt-get update

RUN haxelib setup ~/haxelib && \
    haxelib install lime && \
    haxelib install openfl


CMD ["sh", "-c"]
```

However it does not work properly:
[image: Workspace got mangled]

Additionally I can't get any logs, as trying to open the terminal results in

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd) "/workspaces/e9d1a4e0e6c117e14accaa9eff92c0d10446e1eb5f284b3c9438541c20734591" does not exist.
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a folder *e9d1a4e0e6c117e14accaa9eff92c0d10446e1eb5f284b3c9438541c20734591* within your workspaces folder? The gui has a yellow ! indicating the issue

Comment: The hash-named folder is created correctly in a different setup by devcontainer wrapper docker image I presume. It has to work automatically

Comment: When you hit "Open Workspace" and select a workspace that does exist what happens? Something in your setup is not working, obviously, because VS believes the workspace does not exist.

Comment: That was a good advice, it does in fact open now a differently named workspace correctly. So it's fairly close, except on each "Rebuild container" I have to choose a workspace manually

Comment: It might not matter but can you document that portion of your problem.

Comment: In my opinion, the error message is misleading.
What is should say is "path not found" - for some reason when it connected to the container, it had a bad default path.